# .Net Core 2.1 - Dns.GetHostEntry returns multiple IP's

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to write a socket server that will listen on the host DNS instead of its IP address, so I have this code to resolve the DNS:

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("Host DNS"));
```

The problem is, that `ipHostInfo.AddressList` returns an array with multiple IP's some of them may be of Docker containers running on my machine.

Is there a way to get the single IP address related to the specific host DNS directly from the DNS server?

Comment: You can have many net interfaces, physical or virtuals and have different addresses for Docker. If you use NAT your external ip will be different then local too. Also 127.0.0.1 will also recognized as localhost. I suggest to manually set ip address that you want to use in your app.

Comment: I know, but for this task it is not an option. I must use DNS only and find a way to figure out the correct IP.